# modify attributes of sender in swift

Tags: swift, sender

How can attributes be modified from the sender in swift? For example, if I have a multiple buttons that are connected to the same event handler, how can I modify the attributes of the button (say, the title) that was pressed?

```
@IBOutlet weak var grade_preK: UIButton!

@IBAction func gradeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.title = "New Title"  
}
```

The handler here returns the error "Cannot assign to 'title' in 'sender'". How then, can attributes be changed on the sender of the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created this, Interface Builder may have given you the option to declare `sender` to be `UIButton` rather than `AnyObject` (it does have that option; you may not have noticed it). You could have chosen that, or you can fix it now:

```
@IBAction func gradeButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
```

And now `sender` is of the right type so you can modify it (and it is reasonable style to do so in Cocoa).

(Note that `UIButton` actually has a `setTitle(_ title: String?, forState state: UIControlState)` method, not a `setTitle()` method, so that's what you probably meant to call.)